# How does persistent mapped buffers work in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, gpu, vbo

In OpenGL 4.4 there was a nice extension added: [ARB_buffer_storage](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/buffer_storage.txt)

How does persistent buffers work (or might work) - using `MAP_COHERENT_BIT` and `MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT` set ?

- Is there some special intermediate buffer?
- Why it can be usually faster than normal mapped buffers?

Comment: The behaviour is probably implementation dependant. It will likely depend on many factors how it works including allocation size, memory location (GPU or system). That said for me, having intermediate buffers is against the spirit of this spec and unless it is for compatibility reasons, where support would be otherwise impossible, I'd not expect an implementation to behave in this way. By what metric do you mean they are faster than normal mapped buffers? Pure throughput, or are you including time to lock a normal buffer?

Comment: Persistently mapped buffers are _not_ faster, they are slower. However, they are faster in the particular update-data-every-frame scenario for which they are intended, since you avoid driver memory management and client/server sync. They are likely implemented simply as a pinned block of memory which the GPU can DMA from (though this will depend on the implementation).

Comment: ok, I see. So they are mainly useful in update-every-frame scenarios. I've found some benchmark regarding particles: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=32169.0

Comment: It is a good question. Why nobody from the commentators answered it?