# What is the fastest cross-platform way to retrieve certain vertecies into CPU?

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpgpu

I'm working on an app where I pass a camera pose to the GPU who will generate textures containing different info about the visible vertecies of an object (normals depth ...)
Based on these info, I want to select some verticies and go through the generated textures to retrieve all the info of these verticies into the CPU.

I've done some reading and the best way seems to use the Trasform Feedback.
However, many seem to disapprove like [the last comment here](https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/cuda-opengl-transform-feedback-compute-shaders-for-particle-systems#23286000002014029) or [this blog](http://jason-blog.jlekstrand.net/2018/10/transform-feedback-is-terrible-so-why.html) and opt for the compute shaders.

Comment: Transform feedback has nothing to do with "retrieving" vertices "into the CPU".

Comment: Transform feedback should work just fine for that task (old but gold). No compute shaders MacOS for exampel.

Comment: Thnx that's what I wanted to hear :)
It was added in 2006 to OpenGL (13 years ago!) isn't there a new replacement?

Comment: @user6138759 Cross-Plattform and with older Smarhphones still circulating around see [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/#OpenGL) and [here](https://www.statista.com/statistics/271774/share-of-android-platforms-on-mobile-devices-with-android-os/) the upper limit should be here [OpenGL ES 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES#OpenGL_ES_3.0) VERSION > 3.2 means Geometry and Tessellation. On the iOS [link](https://www.statista.com/statistics/565270/apple-devices-ios-version-share-worldwide/) OpenGL ES is deprecated. Get a Framework and work out a solution from their. :)

Comment: @user6138759 same thing for desktop [Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_intro/opengl_intro.html) Means you still can run OpenGL 4.2 means [Image Load Store](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store) could be an option. And again Geometry and Tessellation shaders.

Answer (score 0):

[Transform feedback](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback) mechanism is not your solution. It is good for capturing current state of data on GPU and update it for the next draw call on GPU without the need to perform GPU to CPU and back ping-pong for the sake of data update. [Particles rendering](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial28/tutorial28.html) is one of popular use cases for transform feeedback.
You have't said what's your target platform so it is hard to understand your hardware limitations/capabilities,but here are few ways to download host (CPU) updates without stalling rendering pipeline:

1. Use [PBO ping-pong](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html). If you can write your data to a texture,you can [download as well as upload from/to GPU asynchronously](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0356-GTC2012-Texture-Transfers.pdf) using Pixel buffer Objects. if you read the doc in the link you can also see that you can take it even further with threaded transfer using shared context.These techniques speed up transfer time dramatically.
2. If you work with buffers,and have access to persistent  mapping features (OpenGL 4.4),you can try double and even triple buffering,which is sort of "PBO ping-pong" as described above, but using buffers. [Here](https://www.bfilipek.com/2015/01/persistent-mapped-buffers-in-opengl.html) this concept is explained in detail,but the general idea is to map persistently a buffer 3x of the size in use,and every frame read from one of 3 parts on host,while write to another one of 3 parts on device. Pinned block of memory is visible to GPU,[probably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777368/how-does-persistent-mapped-buffers-work-in-opengl), via DMA ,and while in general persistent mapped buffers aren't any faster than regular mapped,they do reduce driver overhead noticeably for every frame updates.
3. Heavy canon like use of CUDA or OpenCL in separate thread. I don't know how it is done with OpenCL,but with CUDA you can set CUDA context in separate thread, map [GL resource](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OPENGL.html#group__CUDART__OPENGL) like buffer or texture to CUDA owned resources and then using Producer - Consumer paradigm read data to host from CUDA mapped GL buffer,while keep rendering in OpenGL thread. Of course you will have to synchronize between the threads as OpenGL [shouldn't access](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__INTEROP_1gad8fbe74d02adefb8e7efb4971ee6322) buffer while it is mapped to CUDA context,as the results of such an access will be undefined.

I personally would go with option 2 + use shared context and thread for persistently mapped pointer for data read out.It has its complications around synchronization,but if done right can give your very fast solution.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting response. As I mentionned in the question, I want to read-back only certain vertices not the whole texture and for PBOs I have to use glReadPixel so reading the whole texture. But with a geometry shader + transform feedback I can select texels to retrieve and I dont have to know the number of texels I'm gonna retrieve from my application side. And for 3/ I'm only using OpenGL I don't want to add CUDA and OpenCL.